# scatterplot3d trouble: " object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Tags: r, plot, closures, lm

I get an error message when I am trying to plot the regression plane of a dataset ([Data source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hzeehvqx429b3s/OBSvsMOD_NEE_hourly.csv?dl=0)) using the scatterplot3d package.

The error says:

> Error in scatterplot3d$plane3d : 
>     object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

I could easily plot the data, however the error pop up when I try to plot the fit model.

This is my code:

```
scatterplot3d(CO2umol,NEE,GS,pch=20, highlight.3d=TRUE, main="NEE: AC vs EC vs MOD")
fit <- lm( GS ~ CO2umol+NEE,  OBSvsMOD_NEE_hourly)
scatterplot3d$plane3d(fit)
```

Do you have a clue? I am wondering about the NA's, but I am not quite sure about how to face the issue.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ss <- scatterplot3d(CO2umol,NEE,GS,pch=20, 
   highlight.3d=TRUE, main="NEE: AC vs EC vs MOD")
fit <- lm( GS ~ CO2umol+NEE,  OBSvsMOD_NEE_hourly)
ss$plane3d(fit)
```

You should be working with the `plane3d` element of the *object that is returned by `scatterplot3d`* (`ss$plane3d`), not trying to find a `plane3d` element in `scatterplot3d` itself ...